# Yocto. Package version generated by git command

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake

Is there any option to set package version in recipe from git output?
I have a recipe thats always download latest revision from git by setting `SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"` , and want to bitbake to set package version "PV" to output of `git describe --abbrev=4 --dirty --always --long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to manage some code to archive this goal, but I feel that this solution is not the **perfect one**, but anyway please see why.

Firstly let's compare output git command (*git describe --abbrev=4 --dirty --always --long*)* based on recipe and from git repository, to be sure that it's working as expected:

- *PV* generated by bitbake based on recipe:

  ```
  $ bitbake --environment hello-world | grep ^PV=
  PV="4b5f"
  ```
- output git repository:

  ```
  $ git remote -v | grep fetch
  origin  https://github.com/leachim6/hello-world.git (fetch)
  $ git describe --abbrev=4 --always --long
  4b5f
  ```

How to archive that ? For test purpose I chose [hello-world](https://github.com/leachim6/hello-world) repository, lately on to define the *PV* I use *bitbake* [python function](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#python-functions) approach that allows me to set output from such function to *PV*, recipe content:

```
$ cat ../meta-test/recipes-hello-world/hello-world/hello-world_git.bb
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=2c4ac2930215d12ccb72d945112a0fa3"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/leachim6/hello-world.git;protocol=https"
SRCREV = "4b5ff1ef90ceb442f5633fc9e5d28297ac0f69ff"

PV = "${@define_pn(d)}"

def define_pn(d):
    import subprocess
    source_dir = d.getVar('DL_DIR') + "/git2/github.com.leachim6.hello-world.git/"
    cmd = "git describe --abbrev=4 --always --long"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, cwd=source_dir)
    out, err =  proc.communicate()
    return out.decode("utf-8").rstrip()
```

My main about this solution is how to setup properly **source_dir** variable in python function, that will be *much* flexible. I was trying to use the **${S}** variable for instance but without luck - I got python errors during parsing recipe - [gist with error](https://gist.github.com/lukaszgard/79d0fde65ebb63025219488ed426baed). I am not so advanced in *bitbake* code, but maybe someone else could provide better way to setup this proper path.

*while I was uses the original command with *--dirty* flag, In *bitbake* output there was PV="4b5f-dirty", without it the output is the same as in the git repository.

Comment: I know, that fixed path is not the best solution, but your solution is good for me. Thank for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work. BitBake is trying to expand the PV variable *before* it runs `do_fetch`, so the directory does not exist yet. Unfortunately I don't think git can do a remote describe, so it would be needed to force the fetcher to run (at which pointer we might know the download directory from it, too).

Comment: Your right i had same issue when i was trying to build it from scratch. In my situation we abandoned this approach.

Comment: Guys You are right, my proposal is not working as expected. @to

Comment: ... @tomasz3dk can You un-vote my post then I will delete it. However right now I think that setting PV based on git revision is not possible, or did You manage it somehow ?